# use a ListBox to Filter Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, checkbox, listbox

I have a ListBox and a DataGrid, DataGrid displays price quotes supplied by suppiers, while ListBox displays the supplier list. What I want to achieve is to check/uncheck the supplier in the supplier list and filter the DataGrid such that DataGrid will only show quotes from the suppliers that are checked in the ListBox.

The difficulty I am facing now is,

I have a unique list of Suppliers

```
class Supplier
{
    bool IsChecked {get; set;}
    Person Supplier {get; set;}

}

ObservableCollections<Supplier> SupplierList;
```

I have a list of Quote

```
class Quote
{
    double Price {get; set;}
    Supplier Supplier{get; set;}
    Quote(double price, Supplier supplier)
    {
         Price = price;
         Supplier = supplier;
    }
}

ObservableCollections<Quote> QuoteList;
```

QuoteList is bind to DataGrid, while SupplierList is bind to ListBox.

When I check/uncheck the SupplierList in the ListBox, Can the Suppliers in the Quote be changed at the same time? and How to achieve that?

Comment: Are items in `SupplierList` and `Supplier` instances in quotes from `QuoteList` the same instances? If no, how two instances of supplier can be checked for equivalence?

Comment: @Dennis hi, i actually like to make them the same instance, but when I use a Supplier instance from SupplierList to construct a Quote in QuoteList, it get copied and dont share the same IsChecked property anymore. How can I design my class to make them the same instance?

Comment: Show `Quote` construction code, please.

Comment: @Dennis now edited with Quote constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you dont need to produce an ObservableCollection, you are not locked into having a physical list instead of just a query.

I would suggest that you introduce a SupplierQuoteQuery class (see [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) for more info on ViewModels) to support this view, it needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged so that you can advise when your filtered list changes.

You need to wire up some way of notifying the SupplierQuoteQuery class when your IsChecked changes, and that should cause the PropertyChanged to be called for a new Property FilteredQuotes.

```
public IEnumerable<Quote> FilteredQuotes { get {
  return from x in Quotes where x.Supplier.IsChecked select x; } }
```